# Java Idea перестала видеть класс length, но иногда

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Еще только познаю Java, но с таким столкнулся впервые. Посреди всего внезапно перестал видеть .length, ругается, предлагает создать отдельный класс, но, как мне кажется, это не совсем то решение которое должно быть? В чем причина? Версия jdk 18

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас там for вне метода... :)